# Stuffing HTML in an about: URL with Chrome

Tags: html, internet-explorer, google-chrome, url, url-scheme

In Internet Explorer back in the day you could type this into the URL bar:

```
about:<body bgcolor=red>
```

And the screen would turn red.

Is there an equivalent "heredoc" syntax for loading HTML via a URL in Chrome?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A data URI, perhaps?

```
data:text/html,<body bgcolor=red>
```

Ironically, this does not work on IE, although [MSDN claims](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc848897.aspx) this is due to security reasons.

Comment: Love it. I remember we were at a trade show and had a locked-down laptop and no cell phones and needed a timer. BAM! Javascript in the URL.